# Provide VM with Minishift, Minikube or minimalist Kubernetes from oVirt

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, minikube, minishift, ovirt

I've oVirt running and providing several VMs (Debian, CentOS and RedHat), now I want to provide VMs with minimalist Kubernetes cluster running inside to developers.

For example, Minishift creates a VM with Openshift (Kubernetes) locally, but now since we have oVirt, we want to provide these VMs for that developers can get access remotely to them.

Has anyone experimented with this?. Any idea is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've collected from oVirt and Openshift forums different suggestions. There are 2 options:

1. Generate from Minishift/Minikube a VM which will be imported as an oVirt Template.

   - [oVirt Templates](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/vmm-guide/chap-Templates)
2. Use oVirt Ansible Roles and Openshift Ansible. This will require to understand what are the Openshift requirements and configurations in oVirt:

   - [Openshift on RHV4(oVirt)](http://ttps://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/reference_architectures/2017/pdf/deploying_red_hat_openshift_container_platform_3_on_red_hat_virtualization_4/Reference_Architectures-2017-Deploying_Red_Hat_OpenShift_Container_Platform_3_on_Red_Hat_Virtualization_4-en-US.pdf)
   - [oVirt Ansible Roles](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-ansible)
   - [Openshift Ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible)

Regards.